# Создание объектов из данных файла

Tags: java

Файл имеет структуру:

> Name;UniqueNumber;Price;Count;Production
>
> Windows 7;0123;2000;20;Microsoft
>
> Asus 123;666;500;Notebook Asus;3;Asus

Читаю линии в файле, с помощью `String split` создаю массив строк.
Создаю объекты `new Product(name,uniqueName,price,count,production)`, поочередно внося строки в качестве параметров.

В первом случае (строка `Windows`) все хорошо, во втором случае (строка `Asus`) есть запись `Notebook Asus`, которую надо удалить-"переступить", чтоб корректно внести данные в конструктор.

Comment: Если дадите код, начиная от `"с помощью String split создаю массив строк"` и заканчивая `"внося строки в качестве параметров"`, то могу попытаться засунуть туда проверочку)

Comment: Похоже, что файл с данными имеет не однородную структуру или есть какие-то правила, о которых вы умалчиваете

Comment: Это `CSV` что-ли?

Answer (score 0):

просто условие в цикле

```
if(name == "Notebook Asus") continue;
```

continue; - пропуск итерации цикла

Answer (score 0):

Если вы получили массив строк, то по 3-й строке Asus он выглядит так:
String [] mas = {"Asus 123", "666", "500", "Notebook Asus", "3", "Asus"};
Можно сделать маппинг так:
Product product = new Product(mas[0], mas[1], mas[2], mas[3], mas[4]);